Framer motion does not transition when closing component
I'm having trouble with transition effects when closing a conditional rendering component like a sidebar. It works normally when opening, but not when closing. Can someone help me?
    const { cartBarOpen } = useSelector((rootReducer: any) => rootReducer.cartBarReducer)

    const handleCloseCart = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch({ type: cartBarActionTypes.CLOSE });
        }, 500);
    };

    const containerVariants = {
        hidden: {
            x: "100%"
        }, // Inicialmente, a janela estará fora da tela à direita
        visible: {
            x: 0, // Quando a janela estiver visível, ela estará na posição original (x: 0)
            transition: {
                duration: 0.5,
                type: 'tween',
                ease: 'easeInOut'
            }
        },
        exit: {
            x: "100%",
            transition: {
                duration: 0.5,
                type: 'tween',
                ease: 'easeInOut'
            }
        }, // Ao sair, a janela deve deslizar de volta para fora da tela à direita
    };

return (
        <>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {cartBarOpen && (
                    <CartContainer
                        variants={containerVariants}
                        initial="hidden"
                        animate={cartBarOpen ? "visible" : "hidden"}
                        exit="hidden"
                    >
                        <ContainerTop>
                            <CartTitle>Carrinho de Compras</CartTitle>
                            <CloseCart onClick={handleCloseCart}>X</CloseCart>
                        </ContainerTop>
                        <CartContent>
                        </CartContent>
                        <ContainerBottom>
                        </ContainerBottom>
                    </CartContainer>

                )}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </>
    );

I've tried everything, but I couldn't get any answers... Even with Styled-Components keyframes it doesn't work...

You have duplicated logic. When using AnimatePresence, you don't need to change the animate prop when you want the element to leave/enter. Change animate={cartBarOpen ? "visible" : "hidden"} to animate="visible".
<AnimatePresence>
    {cartBarOpen && (
        <CartContainer
            variants={containerVariants}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
            exit="hidden"
        >
            <ContainerTop>
                <CartTitle>Carrinho de Compras</CartTitle>
                <CloseCart onClick={handleCloseCart}>X</CloseCart>
            </ContainerTop>
            <CartContent>
            </CartContent>
            <ContainerBottom>
            </ContainerBottom>
        </CartContainer>
    )}
</AnimatePresence>


I had already tried this, but there is still no transition effect when closing the window... If it helps, here's the rest of the code: https://github.com/danielgoncalves2023/project_mks/tree/master/src

Can you provide a Minimal Reproducible Example? I recreated the basic functionality in this example. It's hard to tell what it could being able to reproduce it.
